# How to check if an array is an array in JScript?

Tags: jscript, jscript.net

I am trying to port this Javascript code to JScript, but I am not familiar with the base library.

They are supposed to be a compatible languages but this ain't working... the following code gives me a 'method or property not supported by the object' error.

```
 if (Array.isArray(options.boolFlags)) {
   // ...
 }
```

Is there an equivalent way to check for array type in JScript.Net?

Comment: I was trying to translate a js file to jscript.net, but I ended up making a program to embed an actual JS engine (v8) and run it. ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `x instanceof Array` if that's what you want?

Comment: Yes, it worked. You know also the `JSON.stringify` equivalent in Jscript.Net ?

Comment: @beppe9000 You need to write your own